# Declaring variables in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to follow a tutorial which says if we don't want to initialise a variable in swift we can do the following;

```
var year:Integer
year = 2;
```

However, if I declare the above block of code I get an error

> "use of undeclared type Integer"

If i use the following instead it works;

```
var year:integer_t
year = 2;
```

Why do I need to do this yet the tutorial can use the first method?

Thanks

Edit : screen shot from tutorial

[image]

Comment: Swift has no type called Integer, there is a type called Int, Double, CGFloat for numbers.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use an Int, not Integer.

```
var year:Int
year = 2
```

**Note**: You can do this in one line

```
var year:Int = 2
```

and use type inference

```
var year = 2
```

I've been blogging a little about Swift if you're interested, starting here:

http://alblue.bandlem.com/2014/09/swift-introduction-to-the-repl.html

(You can subscribe to the feed at http://alblue.bandlem.com/Tag/swift/)

Answer (score 3):

If the variable never changes, you should declare a **constant** instead.

```
let year: Int = 2
```

...or with type inference:

```
let year = 2
```

Note that Swift infers `Int` when you assign a whole number to a variable/constant and `Double` when you assign a fraction.

Answer (score 0):

First it's **not** `Integer`, that's the type in Swift but `Int`.

**Using Type Annotation:**

```
var year : Int
year = 2
```

**Using Type Inference:**

```
var year = 2;
```

Here the type `Int` is inferred by the compiler during the assignment of the `integer literal` to the variable `year`.

Answer (score -1):

In addition if you have created a third party for others and you want a value to enter from user. The you can create variable with the placeholder.

```
var APIKey: String = <"Place API key here">
```

Answer (score -2):

In swift book said that **“A constant or variable must have the same type as the value you want to assign to it. However, you don’t always have to write the type explicitly”**.
The var year that you first assign it a int type value,so you can't assign another type value to it.